# What's wrong in my query

Tags: ms-access

I wonder what is wrong with this query, it return too much rows (non unique values)

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM Arkusz1 tt
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ONTSERIALNUMBER, MAX(ONTBEUP) AS MaxBEUP
    FROM Arkusz1
    GROUP BY ONTSERIALNUMBER
) groupedtt 
    ON tt.ONTSERIALNUMBER = groupedtt.ONTSERIALNUMBER AND
       tt.ONTBEUP = groupedtt.MaxBEUP
```

despite the fact that subquery working correctly:

```
SELECT ONTSERIALNUMBER,
       MAX(ONTBEUP) AS MaxBEUP
FROM Arkusz1
GROUP BY ONTSERIALNUMBER
```

Comment: Elaborate on what you mean by `return too much rows` ...

Comment: I mean that it do not return unique values as the subquery

Comment: At first glance: Is ONTBEUP unique for each ONTSERIALNUMBER ?

Comment: There are many values for each serial number (time is unique in this database) , I want to query max(ONTBEUP) for each ONTSERIALNUMBER having also 3rd column but no agreggated

Comment: Can there be a tie for max for a given serial number?

Comment: You have not answered my question. If ONTBEUP is not necessary unique for a given ONTSERIALNUMBER, its normal that you have duplicates and the answer from Tim below addresses the issue.

Comment: To elaborate on the comment by @ThomasG, you may need to further restrict your query to define a group such that it will only have a single record.

Comment: Yes there can be tie for max , I did not thought about that. You are right. Is there any chance to get random row from those one ? The power value is quite comparable and I need it just for statistic

Answer (score 0):

If your query is returning records which appear to be duplicate, it simply means that more than one record can correspond to a given serial number and maximum beup value.  The quick fix here is to just use `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tt.*
FROM Arkusz1 tt
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ONTSERIALNUMBER, MAX(ONTBEUP) AS MaxBEUP
    FROM Arkusz1
    GROUP BY ONTSERIALNUMBER
) groupedtt 
    ON tt.ONTSERIALNUMBER = groupedtt.ONTSERIALNUMBER AND
       tt.ONTBEUP = groupedtt.MaxBEUP
```

Comment: Not exacly, only ONTSERIALNUMBER should be unique , so I get the max(ONTBEUP) value for each SERIALNUMBER but I need also power value (3rd column) which the particular row will have